# oracle express application builder is not shown

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

i can't see the application builder icon on oracle Express !

what is the problem ?

should i enable or disable some thing ?

Comment: Need more information than that to be able to help. What "Application Builder"? Are you talking Oracle Application Express? Is your question that you have installed Oracle XE and you don't know how to start Application Express?

Comment: Also, it is possible (and advisable) to upgrade the version of Application Express from the v2.1 that came with XE. Apex 4 is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the icon images are missing then you need to rerun apxldimg.sql

We really need more information in order to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged like system or sys, you have to create a new user, then you have to logout and login with the new user. Magically Application Builder Icon will appear after utility icon.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing right you've managed to login to APEX and don't see the menu item of Application Builder. If so - then you are probably logged on to INTERNAL workspace. 
Change it to any other(create if you don't have it) and choose it on login page. Then will you see the menu and icon.